# How to check if a div has no other visible divs in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to verify if a div with a certain class has visible divs or not in it in jQuery/JavaScript?

Something like:

```
if($('.element').hasVisibleElements()){ //do something } else{ //do something else}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
if($('.element').find(":visible").length > 0 )
```

this is checking if any child element of div is visible or not

Comment: Ok. This is what I was looking for. Is there another way besides using ":visible"? Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous Or else you need to iterate each element and check its display status. I think this should do.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.